# DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator causing @Autowired dependencies to remain null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop, shiro

My project is currently protected using Apache Shiro, and would like to add Shiro annotations for a cleaner source code.

Apache Shiro asks you to include `DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator` in order for Spring AOP to detect it.

My configuration is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.mcac0006.flip")
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppContextConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcRealm shiroRealm;

    @Bean(name="shiroFilter")
    public ShiroFilterFactoryBean getShiroFilter() {
        ShiroFilterFactoryBean bean = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
        bean.setSecurityManager(getSecurityManager());

        return bean;
    }

    @Bean(name="securityManager")
    public DefaultSecurityManager getSecurityManager() {
        return new DefaultWebSecurityManager(shiroRealm);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor() {
        AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor a = new AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor();
        a.setSecurityManager(getSecurityManager());
        return a;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor")
    public DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator() {
        final DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator = new DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator();
        return defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator;
    }
}
```

In this example `shiroRealm` remains null and is causing all its dependants to fail. If I comment-out the last method `defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator()`, shiroRealm is instantiated just fine.

What am I overlooking??

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

`DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator` is a `BeanPostProcessor`. Beans of that type are instantiated and initialized before other beans. However, in this case, your `@Bean` method is also annotated with `@DependsOn` in which case the bean depends on another bean to be initialized before its own initialization can take place.

So before `defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator` can run, `authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor` must be run. That method now depends on `getSecurityManager()`, so that must also be ran first. When it is ran, your `@Autowired` field isn't processed yet because the `BeanPostProcessor` beans haven't all been initialized yet. (A `BeanPostProcessor` processes injections for `@Autowired`.)

If you had a completely separate bean and checked the state of the `shiroRealm`, you would see it as non-null at that point.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer - very well explained. Is it a design issue, or is there some sort of work around to it?

Comment: I'll have to get back to you in a few hours.

Comment: @MatthewCachia I guess you could say it's a limitation of Spring's Java configuration. You can make your `securityManager` depend on the `shiroRealm` bean. (But it's own injections may fail.) I have to review Shiro.